# Ansible - Overwrite values from file1 with coresponding value from file2

Tags: bash, jenkins, ansible

I have 2 files, file1 and file2.

I want ansible to read each line of file 2 and replace the values for the corresponding key in file1.
These files could have more rows, I dont know how to exactly search and replace keys from file2 in file1 and replace corresponding values from file1 with values from file2.
Any help is appreciated... :(
Keys, will not be the same, so I can't hardcode I need to dynamically search and replace.

> File 1 could have different format like .json .js .txt
>
> **ansible 2.7**
>
> key/value format might also be key=value

```
ex.
file1
 abc: cat
 def: horse
 test: house

file2
 def: airplane
 test: blue

Expected resulting file:
file1:
 abc: cat
 def: airplane
 test: blue
```

Thanks I will adapt to this module.

Comment: I can do it in `bash`: `join -t: -a 1 file1 file2 | sed 's/:.*:/:/'`

Comment: While doing it with your example is easy, having a general solution for handling different input formats is **not**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following tree for this example:

```
.
├── test.yml
└── vars
    └── merge_vars
        ├── file1.yml
        └── file2.yml
```

The var files are the same as in your question.

The example playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: import vars from files
      include_vars:
        dir: vars/merge_vars
        name: merged_vars

    - debug: 
        var: merged_vars
```

gives:

```
PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************************************************

TASK [import vars from files] *****************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "merged_vars": {
        "abc": "cat",
        "def": "airplane",
        "test": "blue"
    }
}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: @ChuckB0ris Do you know ahead of time what the file names are?

Comment: Yes, they have the same name (app_name), I adapted the above logic to the ansible role I created and it just copies and renames all the needed files in the same folder as file1.json, file2.json, file3.json, combines them and sends the resulting file to the remote server I deploy on. Thanks everyone for the help, issue is solved.